# DOM element not loaded after React component mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, lifecycle

I'm trying to scroll an anchor into view when my component mounts. I have the following simplified code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Sections = ({ sections }) => {
  const location = useLocation()

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const { hash } = location
    const element = document.getElementById(hash.replace('#', ''))
    console.log('--------------');
    console.log('loaded', loaded);
    console.log('hash', hash);
    console.log('element', element);
    if (loaded && hash && element) {
      try {
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
      } finally {
        // Do nothing
      }
    }
  }, [location, loaded])

  return (
    <div className="Sections">
      {sections.map((section) => (
        <div id={section.title} className="Section__anchor">
          <ReactMarkdown>
            {section.content}
          </ReactMarkdown>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want the page to scroll to the anchor in the url on the initial load.

The effect hook with `[location, loaded]` as dependencies is called whenever the location changes or the component loads. And it properly scrolls to an anchor when the location changes. But I can't seem to find a trigger for when the DOM content is loaded.

The code above produces the following output:

```
index.jsx:49 --------------
index.jsx:50 loaded false
index.jsx:51 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:52 element null
index.jsx:49 --------------
index.jsx:50 loaded false
index.jsx:51 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:52 element null
index.jsx:49 --------------
index.jsx:50 loaded true
index.jsx:51 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:52 element null
index.jsx:49 --------------
index.jsx:50 loaded true
index.jsx:51 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:52 element null
```

So this makes it clear that the react component is mounting *before* the DOM element I'm trying to scroll to is loaded. According to the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), a component is mounted when it is inserted into the tree, and "Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here". So I don't understand why the DOM is still unable to find these elements once the component is mounted.

For what it's worth, I've also tried using `DOMContentLoaded` instead:

```js
const onLoaded = () => {
  setLoaded(true)
}

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoaded);

  return document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoaded);
}, [])
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
index.jsx:55 --------------
index.jsx:56 loaded false
index.jsx:57 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:58 element null
index.jsx:55 --------------
index.jsx:56 loaded false
index.jsx:57 hash #EXTRA%20CREDIT
index.jsx:58 element null
```

So when I use that listener, `DOMContentLoaded` is never even being called. This tells me that the component mount hook is being called *after* `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered. Because if it was called before, the listener event would trigger and `loaded` would be set to true.

So in short, how do I make sure a DOM element is loaded before trying to perform an action on it??

Comment: Is `sections` loaded via ajax? Maybe your component is already renderd, and then the `sections` prop is changed. Also maybe you have a space in your `section.title` so it will be invalid

Comment: The DOM will always be loaded before any useEffect runs, but depending on how your children are retrieved the specific element you're querying might not be available. Regardless, you shouldn't be querying the DOM manually unless absolutely necessary. Instead use a `ref` attached to the relevant child element.